# What is the difference between json.dump() and json.dumps() in python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I searched in [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) official document to find difference between the json.dump() and json.dumps() in python. It is clear that they are related with file write option. 
But what is the detailed difference between them and in what situations one has more advantage than other?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

If you want to dump the JSON into a file/socket or whatever, then you should go with `dump()`. If you only need it as a string (for printing, parsing or whatever) then use `dumps()` (dump string)

As mentioned by [Antti Haapala in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059411/4385621), there are some minor differences on the `ensure_ascii` behaviour. This is mostly due to how the underlying `write()` function works, being that it operates on chunks rather than the whole string. Check his answer for more details on that.

`json.dump()`

> Serialize obj as a JSON formatted stream to fp (a .write()-supporting file-like object
>
> If ensure_ascii is False, some chunks written to fp may be unicode instances

`json.dumps()`

> Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str
>
> If ensure_ascii is False, the result may contain non-ASCII characters and the return value may be a unicode instance

Comment: Can you show an example on how to use dump() to send through socket? I know that I can use dumps() and than encode() to convert to bytes, but is there any shorter way?

Comment: is `dump` (or `with open` and `dump`) asynchronous or will the `dump` (or `with open` and `dump`) completely finish executing before moving onwards in the script?

Comment: I don't understand, what is a concrete use case for `.dump`? why would anyone not want it as a string?

Answer (score 49):

In memory usage and speed.

When you call `jsonstr = json.dumps(mydata)` it first creates a full copy of your data in memory and only then you `file.write(jsonstr)` it to disk. So this is a faster method but can be a problem if you have a big piece of data to save.

When you call `json.dump(mydata, file)` -- without 's', new memory is not used, as the data is dumped by chunks. But the whole process is about 2 times slower.

Source: I checked the source code of `json.dump()` and `json.dumps()` and also tested both the variants measuring the time with `time.time()` and watching the memory usage in htop.

Answer (score 47):

The functions ending with  `s` accept string parameters. The other take file
streams or pointers to files.

Answer (score 7):

One notable difference in **Python 2** is that if you're using `ensure_ascii=False`, `dump` will properly write UTF-8 encoded data into the file (unless you used 8-bit strings with extended characters that are not UTF-8):

`dumps` on the other hand, with `ensure_ascii=False` can produce a `str` or `unicode` just depending on what types you used for strings:

> Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str using this conversion table. If ensure_ascii is False, the result may contain non-ASCII characters and the return value **may be a `unicode` instance**.

(emphasis mine). Note that it may still be a `str` instance as well.

Thus you cannot use its return value to save the structure into file without checking which 
format was returned and possibly playing with `unicode.encode`.

This of course is not valid concern in Python 3 any more, since there is no more this 8-bit/Unicode confusion.

---

As for `load` vs `loads`, `load` considers the **whole** file to be one JSON document, so you cannot use it to read multiple newline limited JSON documents from a single file.

Comment: All text created in a python string object is unicode, but is it safe to assume that generically? i.e. when loading contents from a file?

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves it means you cannot mix binary data with text so that python approves it silently. e.g. `json.dumps([b'123'])` -> `TypeError`.

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves also do note that the strings in JSON documents **must be Unicode**, and **must be** in any of UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32 according to RFC 7159

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! Makes sense

Comment: is `dump` (or `with open` and `dump`) asynchronous or will the `dump` (or `with open` and `dump`) completely finish executing before moving onwards in the script?

Comment: completely finish, except that **dump** might still perhaps have it in buffers...