# Cannot write dictionary to file in python using json.dumps()

Tags: python, json

I'm getting a response from a JSON dumps, and I'm trying to load it in a `log.txt` file, but this doesn't print out anything

My Function

```
def get_customer_last_action_executed(self):
    """
    Get the customer last action executed
    By inputing the CustomerID
    :return:
    """
    payload ={'customerID': self.CustomerID}
    if not self.CustomerID:
        customer_id = raw_input("Please  provide the customer ID:")
        self.CustomerID = customer_id
        # raise Exception('No customerID provided')

    response = self.send_request(self.get_customer_last_action_executed_url + self.CustomerID,
                                 json.dumps(payload),
                                 "GET")

    print response.url, response.status_code
    print response, response.text, response.reason
    if response:
        print self.sucessful_msg
    else:
        print self.error_msg
    with open('log.txt', 'w') as f:
        json.dumps(payload, f)
```

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show  `def self.send_request(...`.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to use is `dump()` not `dumps()`.

**json.dump()**

> Serialize obj as a JSON formatted stream to fp (a .write()-supporting
>   file-like object
>
> If ensure_ascii is False, some chunks written to fp may be unicode
>   instances

**json.dumps()**

> Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str
>
> If ensure_ascii is False, the result may contain non-ASCII characters
>   and the return value may be a unicode instance

Full details can be found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059194/what-is-the-difference-between-json-dump-and-json-dumps-in-python) thread

Comment: Hi it doesnt  still work ,  i've used this , with io.open('log.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        #     f.write(json.dumps(payload, ensure_ascii=False))

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you need to use dump not dump*s*. Remove the "s" :D