# Why do json.dump and json.dumps behave differently?

Tags: python, json, serialization

I use a custom JSONEncoder to alter some values in the `dict` I want to dump.

```
import json

class CustomJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        #obj = dict(obj)
        obj['__key'] += 1

        return super().encode(obj)

data = dict(__key=1)

print('dumps')
print(json.dumps(data, cls=CustomJSONEncoder))

print('dumps', json.dumps(data, cls=CustomJSONEncoder))

json.dump(data, open('test.json', 'w'), cls=CustomJSONEncoder)
print('dump', json.load(open('test.json', 'r')))
```

Running this gives the expected result:

> dumps {"__key": 2}
> dump {'__key': 2}

But when I uncomment the commented-out line (which is required for what I ultimately want to do because I don't want to change the original data), `dumps` and `dump` behave differently:

> dumps {"__key": 2}
> dump {'__key': 1}

Why does this happen? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: See this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059194/what-is-the-difference-between-json-dump-and-json-dumps-in-python

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether that line is commented out. I added print statements to the `encode()` method, and it's not being called from `json.dump()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think the line you commented out has anything to do with it.

Instead, I think the difference is that `json.dumps` calls `encode`, while `json.dump` calls [`iterencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.iterencode), which you have not overwritten. The reason is presumably that iterative encoding is not useful if you store the entire result in memory anyway.

Looking at the [source code for `JSONEncode`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e9569ec43e2376aa77240cd630db4be07e8720f3/Lib/json/encoder.py#L200), it seems that `encode` actually calls `iterencode`, so, depending on what you want to achieve, it might make more sense to overwrite that one instead:

```py
    def iterencode(self, obj, **kwargs):
        obj['__key'] += 1
        return super().iterencode(obj, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Sure would be nice if the documentation mentioned this difference.