# How can I save a list of ipyleaflet markers to a file and load them later on?

Tags: python, google-maps-markers, geojson, ipywidgets, ipyleaflet

I'd like to save a list of ipyleaflet markers so I can load them into another ipyleaflet map later on. I have customized the markers using a MarkerCustom class in order to incorporate another attribute (duration), which works fine. Later on I also split them up into different clusters, so I do not want to save them as one cluster at this stage.

```
from traitlets import List
import ipyleaflet
from ipywidget import HTML

class MarkerCustom(Marker):
    duration=List().tag(sync=True, o=True)
```

My markers are all part of a longer list named `mark`:

```
mark[0]=MarkerCustom(location=[df.loc[index]['latitude'], df.loc[0]['longitude']], icon=icon, draggable=False, title=tooltip, duration=duration_list, popup=HTML('custom text0'))
mark[1]=MarkerCustom(location=[df.loc[1]['latitude'], df.loc[1]['longitude']], icon=icon, draggable=False, title=tooltip, duration=duration_list,popup=HTML('custom text1'))
```

and so on.

How do I save the list `mark` and load it later on?

I have tried solutions using : [shelve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960864/how-to-save-all-the-variables-in-the-current-python-session), [pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745500/how-to-save-a-list-to-a-file-and-read-it-as-a-list-type), and [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778021/how-can-i-save-a-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-file), but none of these seem to work for this data type.
I also looked into the geojson library (particularly [here](https://pypi.org/project/geojson/#custom-classes)), but I am fairly new to this and not very familiar with classes yet. I have tried to adjust my custom Marker class in the following way:

```
from traitlets import List
import ipyleaflet
from ipywidget import HTML
import geojson


class MarkerCustom(Marker):

    duration=List().tag(sync=True, o=True)
    
    @property
    def __geo_interface__(self):
        return {self}
```

and then tried to save one of the markers like this , e.g.:

```
geojson.dumps(mark[0])
```

But the error is: "TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable"

If I use pickle instead, e.g.:

```
import pickle

with open("test", "wb") as fp:   
    pickle.dump(mark[0], fp)
```

The error I get is: "TypeError: cannot pickle '_hashlib.HMAC' object"
(The error is the same if I use the entire list `mark` instead of just one marker, e.g. `mark[0]`)

I have a lot of markers (>1000) in the list, so instead of saving each individual marker `mark[0]`, `mark[1]` etc, I would prefer to save and load them as the list `mark`.

Comment: I would develop a factory function that received a dataframe parameter and return the `MarkerCustom` list. Ipywidgets takes some time to render multiple widgets so using pickle may be faster, can you add your attempt to use pickle?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've updated my question to include my attempt with pickle