# How to fetch vectors for a word list with Word2Vec?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, word2vec

I want to create a text file that is essentially a dictionary, with each word being paired with its vector representation through word2vec. I'm assuming the process would be to first train word2vec and then look-up each word from my list and find its representation (and then save it in a new text file)?

I'm new to word2vec and I don't know how to go about doing this. I've read from several of the main sites, and several of the questions on Stack, and haven't found a good tutorial yet.

Comment: It's quite easy. I had done that in past. Do you want to use any specific language? You can directly use author's code (in C++) to train and extract the vectors. It's simple 600-700 lines of optimized code. I might be able to help with exact arguments if you require it.

Comment: I would prefer Java, but all I really need to do is make a dictionary with any language and then load that text file into my Java program, so any language would probably work

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/ is the original author's code. It's very simple to train. Only thing is this output the vector into a binary file. You can easily convert it to a text file.

Comment: @Naman I'm trying to work with word vector output and as you said some of the words are just represented as numbers. I am working on the part they assigned binary codes to words, but still couldn't decipher it fully. Any suggestion would be great help!

Comment: @patti_jane Sure, you can look into https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html if you are comfortable using python and gensim. It gives you a nice wrapper and some basic functions. If you want pure python code, I can give you that once I am on my personal PC.

Comment: @Naman thank you! I already have several word vector outputs that I trained using the original code, so if possible a method to reconstruct words from binary would be better really, thanks again!

Comment: @patti_jane By reconstruct words, I guess you mean, you want to load a mapping from words to vectors, right? model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('/tmp/vectors.bin', binary=True) should do your work. It will load the binaries and you can get word vectors. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Naman exactly! so i have to use gensim or is there any other way without using it?

Answer (score 25):

The direct access `model[word]` is deprecated and will be removed in Gensim 4.0.0 in order to separate the training and the embedding. The command should be replaced with, simply, `model.wv[word]`.

Using Gensim in Python, after vocabs are built and the model trained, you can find the word count and sampling information already mapped in `model.wv.vocab`, where `model` is the variable name of your `Word2Vec` object.

Thus, to create a dictionary object, you may:

```
my_dict = dict({})
for idx, key in enumerate(model.wv.vocab):
    my_dict[key] = model.wv[key]
    # Or my_dict[key] = model.wv.get_vector(key)
    # Or my_dict[key] = model.wv.word_vec(key, use_norm=False)
```

Now that you have your dictionary, you can write it to a file with whatever means you like. For example, you can use [the pickle library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19201448/2473022). Alternatively, if you are using Jupyter Notebook, they have a convenient 'magic command' `%store my_dict > filename.txt`. Your filename.txt will look like:

```
{'one': array([-0.06590105,  0.01573388,  0.00682817,  0.53970253, -0.20303348,
   -0.24792041,  0.08682659, -0.45504045,  0.89248925,  0.0655603 ,
   ......
   -0.8175681 ,  0.27659689,  0.22305458,  0.39095637,  0.43375066,
    0.36215973,  0.4040089 , -0.72396156,  0.3385369 , -0.600869  ],
  dtype=float32),
 'two': array([ 0.04694849,  0.13303463, -0.12208422,  0.02010536,  0.05969441,
   -0.04734801, -0.08465996,  0.10344813,  0.03990637,  0.07126121,
    ......
    0.31673026,  0.22282903, -0.18084198, -0.07555179,  0.22873943,
   -0.72985399, -0.05103955, -0.10911274, -0.27275378,  0.01439812],
  dtype=float32),
 'three': array([-0.21048863,  0.4945509 , -0.15050395, -0.29089224, -0.29454648,
    0.3420335 , -0.3419629 ,  0.87303966,  0.21656844, -0.07530259,
    ......
   -0.80034876,  0.02006451,  0.5299498 , -0.6286509 , -0.6182588 ,
   -1.0569025 ,  0.4557548 ,  0.4697938 ,  0.8928275 , -0.7877308 ],
  dtype=float32),
  'four': ......
}
```

You may also wish to look into the native [save](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.save) / [load](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.load) methods of Gensim's word2vec.

Comment: What is the difference between `model.wv.get_vector()` and `model.wv.word_vec()`?

Comment: Given methods are deprecated now

Comment: Yet another popular open source python data science library that loves to break their APIs because they can't be bothered to design it well enough the first time.

Answer (score 11):

[Gensim tutorial](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) explains it very clearly.

First, you should create word2vec model - either by training it on text, e.g.

```
 model = Word2Vec(sentences, size=100, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)
```

or by loading pre-trained model (you can find them [here](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/#Pre-trained_word_and_phrase_vectors), for example).

Then iterate over all your words and check for their vectors in the model:

```
for word in words:
  vector = model[word]
```

Having that, just write word and vector formatted as you want.

Comment: Hi, can you add what exactly are `words`. Whether it is `vocab` for `model.wv.vocab` or the words from your corpus.

Comment: It should be `list(model.wv.vocab.keys())`

Answer (score 3):

You can Directly get the vectors through

```
model = Word2Vec(sentences, size=100, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)
model.wv.vectors
```

and words through

```
model.wv.vocab.keys()
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Using this method, the `vectors` do not correspond to the words obtained by taking the `keys`. That is, the the order is not the same, not even when keys are sorted.

Comment: After attempting a few things, I found that `model.wv[model.wv.vocab.keys()]` gives the vectors in the order of keys.

Comment: Hi, After getting the vector, it's not fitting to the model, can you please help me with that, Im stumbling from moring

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use `python` with `gensim` package, then building upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60538986/2064231) and [Gensim Word2Vec Documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) you could do something like this

```py
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

# Take some sample sentences
tokenized_sentences = [["here","is","one"],["and","here","is","another"]]

# Initialise model, for more information, please check the Gensim Word2vec documentation
model = Word2Vec(tokenized_sentences, size=100, window=2, min_count=0)

# Get the ordered list of words in the vocabulary
words = model.wv.vocab.keys()

# Make a dictionary
we_dict = {word:model.wv[word] for word in words}
```

Comment: Your method does not preserve the order of the words. The resulting dict contains the order as `and another here is one`. Is there a way to preserve the order of the sentence?

Comment: @spectre - Python dictionaries do not retain order, so you might have to use an ordered dictionary for that. So you can `import collections` and define `we_dict = collections.OrderedDict()`. Just remember to use the loop without dictionary comprehension to save the results. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

### Gensim 4.0 updates: vocab method is depreciated and change in how to parse a word's vector

##### Get the ordered list of words in the vocabulary

words = list(w for w in model.wv.index_to_key)

#### Get the vector for 'also'

print(model.wv['also'])

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

First train your Word2Vec model like you said.

To get key-vector pairs of a list of words, you can use a convenient method [.vectors_for_all](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.vectors_for_all) that Gensim now provides for KeyedVectors object.

example:

```
words = ["apple", "machine", "learning]
word_vectors = model.wv.vectors_for_all(words)
```

The result is also a KeyedVectors object. After getting the vectors you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using basic python:

```
all_vectors = []
for index, vector in enumerate(model.wv.vectors):
    vector_object = {}
    vector_object[list(model.wv.vocab.keys())[index]] = vector
    all_vectors.append(vector_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

For gensim 4.0:

```
my_dict = dict({})

for word in word_list:
     my_dict[word] = model.wv.get_vector('0', norm = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [this](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4), you may find anything you need including Word2Vec, FastText, Doc2Vec, KeyedVectors and so on...