# How do I split a string into a dictionary?

Tags: python

Trying to split into a dictionary:

```
output = "Port WWN" : 10:00:00:00:xx:xx:xx:01 ,
         "Node WWN" : 20:00:00:00:xx:xx:xx:01
```

tried:

```
d = dict(x.split(": ") for x in output.split("\n"))

print(d)
```

---

```
expected output = 
{Port WWN : 10:00:00:00:xx:xx:xx:01, Node WWN : 20:00:00:00:xx:xx:xx:01}
```

---

getting error:

```
File "/Users/mike/PycharmProject/pyTest/venv/scratch.py", line 6, in <module>
    d = dict(x.split("=") for x in output.split("\n"))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: The problem is that you have a newline at the end, and so your split is going to give you three elements, with the final element being the empty string.  Use `output.splitlines()` instead.

Comment: Related: [Import dictionary from txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848590/import-dictionary-from-txt-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it will solve your issue:

```
output = "Port WWN : 10:00:00:00:xx:xx:xx:01\nNode WWN : 20:00:00:00:xx:xx:xx:01\n"

d = dict(x.split(": ") for x in output.strip().split("\n"))

print(d)
```

sample output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
output = """Port WWN : 10:00:00:00:xx:xx:xx:01
Node WWN : 20:00:00:00:xx:xx:xx:01"""

def Convert(a):
    it = iter(a)
    res_dct = dict(zip(it, it))
    return res_dct

d = [Convert(x.split(' : ')) for x in (output.split("\n"))]
print(d)
```

->

```
[{'Port WWN': '10:00:00:00:xx:xx:xx:01'}, {'Node WWN': '20:00:00:00:xx:xx:xx:01'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### There are several ways to do this... However, this is the most common:

1. Using the JSON library:
   JSON is a native library to Python, and it can be very useful in many scenarios... Here is how you would use it in your scenario:

```
import json
  
# Defining output as the string variable
output = "Port WWN : 10:00:00:00:xx:xx:xx:01\n"
  
# Use "json.loads()"
d = json.loads(output)
  
# print result
print(str(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Use `splitlines` as suggested in comments, and use a regular expression to split each line only once.

```
dict([re.split(r"\s*\:\s*", line, 1) for line in output.splitlines()])
```

Outputs:

```
{'Port WWN': '10:00:00:00:xx:xx:xx:01', 'Node WWN': '20:00:00:00:xx:xx:xx:01'}
```