# How to update dictionary value based on Entry widget: Tkinter

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I am trying to write a condition, under which a value in specified dictionary changes. However, every time I load the file its back to the original value. I would like to save the new value to the dictionary, so when the file is loaded again the new value would show.Any help is appreciated.

I've tried using a different python file for dictionary, but ended up with same results. I gave pickle module a try too. No success. Any help is appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *

dict = {'Andrew': [67, 78, 98], 'William': [56, 90, 42], 'Anna':     [90, 88, 75]}


andrew_var = DoubleVar()
change_first_grade = Entry(root, textvariable=var)
change_first_grade.pack()

andrew_var.set(0)

if andrew_var.get() != 0:
    dict['Andrew'][0] = andrew_var.get()
```

How can I make that when the value in dictionary changes, it is saved, so next time opening file would have had the new value in dictionary.

Comment: You mean changes program script? Why do not save dict  in a file as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201290/how-to-save-a-dictionary-to-a-file/32216025

Comment: you could save it as JSON. But you have to save it every time you change value in dict and load from file at start. It will not do it automatically. The same is when you use pickle or any other file format.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep dictionary in pickle or JSON file but before you save it you have to get value from Entry and put in dictionary. It will not do it automatically.

But you can't get value directly after you create `Entry` because it is not `input()` and it will not wait for data. Function `mainloop()` starts window and everthing before `mainloop()` is execute before you see window.

You may use `Button` to run function which will save it after you put value in `Entry`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import json

def load():
    global data

    try:
        with open('data.json') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

def save(event=None):
    # update dictionary before save
    data['Andrew'][0] = int(entry.get())

    with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

# ---

data = {
    'Andrew':  [67, 78, 98],
    'William': [56, 90, 42],
    'Anna':    [90, 88, 75]
}

# load at start
load()

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
entry.insert('end', data['Andrew'][0])

button = tk.Button(root, text='Save', command=save)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Instead `Button` you could `bind()` key `Enter` to function `save` so it would update data in file.

```
root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
entry.insert('end', data['Andrew'][0])

entry.bind('<Return>', save)

root.mainloop()
```