# Unable to Read Dictionary with Tuple Key from File

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with a tuple as the key.

`my_dictionary[k1, k2] = val`

I save the dictionary to a file, but when I read the file back I get an error.

`dictionary_from_file = dict(dictionary_file.read())`

Error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: Can we see the code you are using to export your dictionnary ?

Comment: How did you safe it to a file? What's in the file?

Comment: you can't create dictionary from string. `dictionary_file.read()` returns a string so you can't create dictionary from it. you can use json file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a dictionary to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201290/how-to-save-a-dictionary-to-a-file)

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo. I didn't know about pickling

Comment: If it helped you solve your problem, please mark it as a ducplicate or delete the question

Answer (score 0):

Python [dictionary constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) doesn't accept string (or parses it to a new dictionary).

In addition, when having a tuple as key, you can use it as the following:

```
dict[(t1,t2)]=v
```

You can take the following steps, and use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to get back the dictionary from the string representation:

```
import ast

# Create dictionary
dict1 = dict()

# Set values to tuple keys
dict1[(1,2)] = 'one two'
dict1[(3,4)] = 'three four'

# {(1, 2): 'one two', (3, 4): 'three four'}
dict_string = str(dict1)
print(dict_string)

# Restore dictionary from string with `ast.literal_eval`
dict2 = ast.literal_eval(dict_string)

# {(1, 2): 'one two', (3, 4): 'three four'}
print(dict2)
```