# How do I count Error using python logger?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

In my test, I am using python logger for logging the messages, My messages are either info or error.
I want to qualify my test as pass or fail based on error messages. Is there any way, I can count error messages using logger and return no. of errors back to my test.

Comment: Can't you just create a variable and increment it on each log

Comment: we can always do that, but always we have to increment that variable, lets say from my test I am printing 1000 error messages, so I have to increment that variables 1000 times. I am looking if logger automates such thing

Comment: I would probably monkeypatch `logging.error` to increment some counter.

Comment: correct. as @AdamSmith, said. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812477/how-many-times-was-logging-error-called) is a similar approach using decorators. I wouldn't expect the logging module to support this because it all depends on your run time code.